# iTunes Connect In App Purchase Pricing not showing up

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, metadata, price

Here I am thinking I've seen it all. But for some unknown reason, I'm trying to create a No-Consumable new In App Purchase (for the million times) thru iTunes Connect, and under the Pricing Section, there is simply nothing.

I have this yellow warning saying "Missing Metadata". In other words, It's impossible for me to use the In App Purchase. I did uploaded Screenshot and filled the display names etc'. The only thing missing is the pricing:

[image]

**Any suggestions would be highly appreciated, thank you!**

Comment: is there country restriction where app will be published?

Comment: @AmodGokhale  hmm No. I sent Apple support a message, waiting for the repsond.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem... Did you get a response from Apple or find a solution ?

Comment: @z0me No.. Can you ask where are you from? Maybe it's country-based issue

Comment: I'm from Switzerland

Comment: @z0me Ah, I'm for Israel. Did you got fixed yet at your end?

Comment: @RoiMulia No, I'm contacting Apple Support. Let's keep ourselves up-to-date if one of us gets more info !

Comment: This is definitely a bug in iTunesConnect: you'll see an error if you open the JavaScript console. I've reported everything to Apple. In the meanwhile, I could change my currency to USD in Account → Personal Details → Currency and set the prices.

Comment: Hey @z0me, thank you for updating, I've sent them a email with all the relevant information. Does changing the currency gave you the option to change the IAP price as well? (for example, from two dollar to one dollar?), or it only changed the IAP currency under the hood?

Comment: No problem! I could change the IAP prices (the option appeared!) after setting the currency to USD

Comment: @z0me WORKS!!!!!! Submit an answer so I can accept. Wow!!!

Comment: @RoiMulia Thanks ! It's done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a bug in iTunesConnect: you'll see an error if you open the JavaScript console. I've reported everything to Apple and they told me that their engineers are working on it.

In the meanwhile, I could change my currency to USD in *Account → Personal Details → Currency* and this bypasses the bug, letting me set the IAP prices.

**Update:** it should be fixed. Here's Apple message:

> The issue you’ve been experiencing with your in-app purchases should
>   now be resolved.
>
> Before attempting to create or edit an in-app purchase, please ensure
>   you’ve updated your paid applications contract to the latest version,
>   and that version has gone into effect.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the error is misleading, in my case it showed metadata is missing in Localization section, but the issue is in Review Information Section, the last section of the page. At first i thought that the Review Information is optional but its Mandatory. Adding an image and description the error goes away.  I think App Store Promotion is suppose to come as a last section because its optional.

Answer (score 0):

I found another version of this which is to do with the Group Reference Name.  This appears under the Product ID on the In App Purchase main screen.  If you set up groups for In App Purchases and make any localisations make sure you also add a localisation for the Group Reference.  The 'missing metadata' error is pinned against the IAP but is actually with the reference group itself (that the IAP is a member of). This typically happened for me when I was creating new IAP and also a new Reference Group for that IAP.  I set the localisation for the IAP but forgot to add one for the Reference Group.  You have to click on the link that the Group Reference has (in blue) to get to where you can enter/update the Subscription Group Reference Name.  The localisation option is on there.